# Print text data on via Bluetooth Zebra printer in Android

Tags: android

Print text data on via Bluetooth Zebra printer in Android,
1. i am face some problem for printing data via Bluetooth so i need full source code so please help me asap.please send me the source code .Thanks in advance

Comment: This question isn't complete, show some effort please.

Comment: More information is needed - what model printer? what exact version of Android?  What have you tried?  Zebra has a couple of SDKs to help with Bluetooth communication.  Make sure you verify which printer you have: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html#mainpartabscontainer_794f=downloads, http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink/zebralink-multiplatform-sdk.html#mainpartabscontainer_4279=downloads